# Unable to invoke WCF Service method from remote machine

Tags: wcf, wcf-client

We created WCF Service and hosted in IIS in a specific machine.
WCF Client is hosted in some other machine which is there in the same LAN.

We were able invoke it. Suddently it started giving error. It is throwing some Timeout exception.

Please tell me the possible scenarios to get this kind of errors. If the WCF Client and WCF Service both are in the same machine, then it is not throwing any error.

Answer (score 0):

Can you ping the service from the machine where the client is set-up?

Are there any firewalls causing this problem? But you said you were originally able to invoke it? are there any event logs to draw from?

You can try set up WCF loging